# Predetermine Height of FlatList item

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

How can I determine the height of an item to be used in a FlatList `renderItem` prop so that I can calculate the number of items to include in its `data` prop in each page of an endless scroll implementation?

Using `ref` like this doesn't work.  Neither does `onLayout`, the function never gets triggered.

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <Card ref={cardRef}>
    ...
  </Card>
);

<FlatList
    data={items}
    renderItem={renderItem}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a solution.  There's obviously no way of knowing, pre render, the height of a rendered `FlatList` item.

Solution - initialize a state prop, `itemHeight` for eg, to `null` or `0`, then send an array containing only a single item to the `data` prop of the `FlatList`.

If the `FlatList` is equipped with an `onLayout` prop, then we could read the height of the entire `FlatList` (which would only be the height of the one item, provided that no list header nor footer exists).

Having measured that, we could then extrapolate how many items per screen and update the `FlatList` `data` prop accordingly.